# Authentication_MissingOrMalformed when executing New-AzureADApplication

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to run this script but I get this error :

> New-AzureADApplication : Error occurred while executing NewApplication
>
> Code: Authentication_MissingOrMalformed
>
> Message: Access Token missing or malformed.

```
Import-Module AzureAD  -Force

$rmAccount = Add-AzureRmAccount
 
$subscriptionId = $rmAccount.Context.Subscription.Id
$tenantId = $rmAccount.Context.Tenant.Id

$tokenCache = $rmAccount.Context.TokenCache
$cachedTokens = $tokenCache.ReadItems() `
        | where { $_.TenantId -eq $tenantId } `
        | Sort-Object -Property ExpiresOn -Descending

$infos = Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenantId `
                -AadAccessToken $cachedTokens[0].AccessToken `
                -AccountId $rmAccount.Context.Account.Id

$clientAadApplication = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "TodoListClient-NativeDotNet" `
                                                  -ReplyUrls "https://TodoListClient-NativeDotNet" `
                                                  -PublicClient $True

$currentAppId = $clientAadApplication.AppId
$clientServicePrincipal = New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId $currentAppId -Tags {WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp}
$currentAppId = $clientAadApplication.AppIds
```

What I'm trying to do is to automatically register a native application in Azure Active Directory without dependency to Azure portal so I logged in using `Add-AzureRmAccount` to get `TenantId` and `SubscriptionId` then I used the cached token to connect to AzureAD to prevent double login.

Answer (score 0):

The token that you obtain when you run `Add-AzureRmAccount` is for the `https://management.core.windows.net` audience, but Azure AD cmdlets [need a token for Azure AD Graph audience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0) (`https://graph.windows.net`). So you can't reuse that token while calling `New-AzureADApplication`. You should choose between Azure RM or Azure AD cmdlets, but not both. But as far as I know `New-AzureRmADApplication` doesn't support creating a native application, so then you should use only [Azure AD cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0).

Comment: The is that Azure AD needs for my case TenantId parameter and it doesn't return the subscriptionId which I need later so before calling Azure AD commands I need to retrieve my tenantId

Comment: You don't need the subscriptionID to use Azure AD cmdlets. You only need to pass the tenantid to connect-azuread (in the case that the account belongs to multiple tenants). If you don't know the tenantid GUID you can see it in portal.azure.com > azure AD > properties. Or you can pass the tenant name (tenant.onmicrosoft.com) instead of the GUID

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but the token you are passing from the AzureRMAccount is not the correct Audience/Resource for the actions you are doing. Just removing that bit and running something like this below will work with the correct Audience and Resource permissions for your Token. You can always check your Token Audience and scope by copying and pasting it at https://jwt.ms (a useful Token debugger by Microsoft).

```
Import-Module AzureAD  -Force
Connect-AzureAD
$clientAadApplication = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "TodoListClient-NativeDotNet" `
                                                  -ReplyUrls "https://TodoListClient-NativeDotNet" `
                                                  -PublicClient $True

$currentAppId = $clientAadApplication.AppId
$clientServicePrincipal = New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId $currentAppId -Tags {WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp}
$currentAppId = $clientAadApplication.AppIds
```

Comment: The problem with Connect-AzureAD is that it requires for me a tenantId because my default account tenantId is my organization tenantId so I need first to run a command that retrieve my directory tenantId and my subscriptionId then I have to call Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $myTenantId besides the authentification should prompt only one time
hope you understand what I want

Comment: you can provide the tenant ID without passing the AadAccessToken.  That AadAccessToken is the main problem with your original script.